# Using Visual Studio C# program in Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, visual-studio-2010, mono

I have written a program using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I need to make sure, that client can run the program from a php page on his Linux server. The problem is, I have never used Linux or php. How should I modify my program, so that it can be run on Linux? I use a lot of libraries as well (like AForge). Thank you!

Comment: Get a virtual machine with linux, install mono and try your program. Use MonoDevelop for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run .Net applications on Linux with mono. Check your program with the no Mono Migration Analyzer - [MoMA](http://mono-framework.com/MoMA)

Comment: MoMA is useful as a first step, but can't replace an actual test.

Answer (score 2):

First, .NET does not run on Linux readily. Mono (http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is an option for this. You need to deploy mono onto the Linux box and configure so that your .NET app can run on it.